# Scrolling text in form title bar

Tags: vb.net

I have written a simple code to scroll the text in the title bar of the form. It is working fine till the length of the text reach 159. After that the text cuts of in the title bar . It does not reach the end of the title bar rather cuts off in the middle of the title bar. Why does this happen?
`tempheader` is a variable that stores the me.text value at form load.

This is the code in the timer tick event with an interval of 100

```
 Me.Text = " " & Me.Text
        If Len(Me.Text) = 159 Then Me.Text = tempheader
```

Comment: It depends how big your form is.

Comment: Isn't this dependent upon how wide your form is?  My guess is your form is wider than the 159 character limit you have included in your code.  Lessen the width as it's running and see what happens.

Comment: My form is the MDIform and it is maximized. My form is wider than 159, but like i said it cuts at length of 159 , which is why i included the above code. Without the above code, when the len reaches 159, the text disappears.

Comment: Show us the rest of the code. The line of code that you put in to work around something isn't useful - the code that 's broken is useful!  What's `tempHeader`?  Also, which version of Windows are you running here, and is this WinForms or WPF?

Comment: Intriguingly, I can replicate this in a WinForms app - but the length my caption is cut off is 255 chars.  This appears (by eye) to be the maximum length of text that would fit in a maximised window on my screen - but if I resize the window across two monitors it won't exceed that limit.

Comment: i hope there is a solution for this with the form displayed in one screen!!

Comment: I was also able to replicate by removing the limit as well, but it limits for me to @ 230 characters. at 1600x900 resolution.  It doesn't matter how wide I start the form either (I thought it might be limited by the startup size).  My guess, since we all got different length values) is that it is resolution dependent perhaps?

Comment: I think it depends on the text size. My text length was 9.

Comment: Also, even though I use multiple monitors, it wrapped to the other monitor before disappearing.

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking it may be a limit of 255 characters based upon the way old versions of vb worked.  My suggestion to @Nelson is to perhaps create a docked label at the top that will allow the scrolling and hide the title bar.  Just a thought.

Comment: it happens only when you are dynamically trying to change the title. For static title ,it takes any length.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..

```
Dim g As Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics()

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Static sPace As String

    sPace &= " "
    Me.Text = sPace & Me.Text
    If g.MeasureString(Me.Text, Me.Font).Width >= Me.Width Then
        Me.Text = tempheader
        sPace = ""
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: @Nelsons .. I've been tried it in my VS 2005 and it worked ! .. What result you've got ?

Comment: It still doesnt go till the end of the form. It cuts off at position 159.

Comment: @Nelsons .. There's running text till the right side of form and then changed with other text .. that in my VS 2005 .. now, I'm not so sure what's really problem here ..

Answer (score 0):

*Lol I know this is an old post but I came across it whilst looking for something else anyway I just use a custom titlebar for scrolling text. Just create an empty form, doubleclick it delete all of the code and add the code from below. Go back and delete the form from the project and save it as a dll. You just need to import it back and add it to your toolbar and you can use it in any projects.*

---

```
Imports System.Drawing
Public Class CustomTitlebar
Inherits Windows.Forms.Panel
  Public Sub ColourTitleText(ByRef panelBG As Color, ByRef txtBG As Color, ByRef txtFC As Color)
    Dim textbox1 As New Windows.Forms.TextBox
    Dim Psize As New Point(26, 200)
    Me.Size = New Point(26, 200)
    Me.BackColor = panelBG
    Me.BorderStyle = Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None
    Me.Dock = Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Top
    Me.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 9.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
    textbox1.Name = "Textbox1"
    textbox1.BackColor = txtBG
    If Not txtFC = Nothing Then
        textbox1.ForeColor = txtFC
    End If
    textbox1.BorderStyle = Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None
    textbox1.Size = New Size(Psize.X - 4, 20)
    textbox1.Location = New Point(3, 3)
    textbox1.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 9.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
    textbox1.Multiline = False
    textbox1.Text = "Coded by tHE_alCHMist 2010"
    Me.Controls.Add(textbox1)
  End Sub
End Class
```

---

*Put this in a timer* "CustomTitlebar1.Text = MarqueeLeft(CustomTitlebar1.Text)"

---

*and then put this function somewhere*

```
Public Function MarqueeLeft(ByVal Text As String)
    Dim Str1 As String = Text.Remove(0, 1)
    Dim Str2 As String = Text(0)
    Return Str1 & Str2
End Function
```

---

*Finally remember to dock it with the top of the form and I hope someone finds this code useful.*